# Removing Duplicates from a Column but make columns on another sheet the outcome with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I am trying to remove duplicate IDs from a column and paste the outcome onto another sheet.  My current workaround is to just copy the entire column to the new sheet first and remove the duplicates there but that is very taxing right now as there are 60k rows and I want to now do this for multiple columns.

Question: Is there a better way to do this so I dont have to copy the column over first.

Here is my current code.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(4)

ws.Range("A1:A" & rowz) = ws2.Range("A1:A" & rowz)

with ws2
Set CtrlID = ws2.Range("A1:A" & rowz)
CtrlID.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
end with
```

Comment: I believe your method is the most efficient way to do this.

Comment: Damn thats what I was afraid of I have been trying to use either an Array or dictionary to hold the values but I havent been successful in those attempts

Comment: Like Dave has said this is quite an efficient way to go about it. Using collections for this would probably be an overkill. Stick with your current code. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be a better site to post this question. Make sure you include some facts about how many rows there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble implementing the Dictionary approach, you could try this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim dict as Object
Dim r as Range
Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsx")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets(4)

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Assign each value to the dictionary
' overwrites existing values and ensures no duplicates
For each r in ws.Range("A1:A" & rowz).Cells
    dict(r.Value) = r.Value
Next

'## Put the dictionary in to the other worksheet:
ws2.Range("A1").Resize(Ubound(dict.Keys) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)

Set dict = Nothing
```

**HOWEVER** I don't really see a reason to re-invent the wheel. You could run some tests to see which is faster.

Comment: Building this and ill post time diff between this and my others once done

Comment: The Dictionary way took 1.660156 seconds
My Original method took 3.867291 seconds

Comment: On large sets of data you will notice that sort of gain with dictionary or collection -- performing the operation in memory is almost *always* faster than manipulating the worksheet objects.  Cheers!