# delete duplicate data on 2 columns with more than 10k each

Tags: excel, vba

**Painting a picture...**

I work in the shoe industry and I'm using excel spreadsheets to improve records. Now I'm planning to expanding to [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com).

**Problem statement:**

I have 2 columns with more than 10000 cells each. One is my own record and the other is the online inventory. I need to delete duplicate values in both columns in order to get a common record so I can update my inventory. I have MS Access, I've tried queries but nothing happened so I guess I am doing something wrong with the wizard.

**Summary:**

*How do I import an .xls into Microsoft Access and remove the duplicate entries?*

Comment: Data tab > Remove Duplicates

Comment: Thanks for revising my question. English isn't my strongest asset. :)

Comment: As Tmdean mentions, this is possible directly with Excel. Is there a reason it needs to be done by Access?

Comment: aland:I am starting something similar to a database...I say "similar" as I don't have enough knowledge to do a real one...but I would like to have it in order to build a proper one to use @ Amazon. I've read in several foruns about Excel that it doesn't work on more than 10000 records.

Comment: Remove Duplicates doesn't have any limitation. I think the limit you read about is when you pull down the autofilter menu on a column. It only shows the first 10,000 unique values in the column in the filter menu (and it will warn you when this happens).

Comment: You can delete duplicates in Excel with a method like [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935759/removing-duplicates-from-a-column-but-make-columns-on-another-sheet-the-outcome/). User-testing suggests that for large volume of records, it is faster than using the native "Remove Duplicates" option.

Comment: @Tmdean: well..you are right all along.

Answer (score 0):

*Basically you could solve this many many ways...here are a couple solutions.*

---

### **Migrate to Access and remove duplicates:**

1. Migrate **Excel** into **Access**: [Click Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/move-data-from-excel-to-access-HA010342703.aspx)
2. Delete Duplicate Entries in **Access**: [Click Here](http://www.datawright.com.au/access_resources/deleting_duplicate_records_in_access.htm)

---

### **Remove duplicates in Excel**

How to remove duplicates in **Excel**: [Click Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx)

Comment: Liked the article about migrating XLS into Access. It will be quite useful.

Comment: Please be careful on what you mean by duplicates. Two rows/records can have same ID but different data points across other fields. Another similar solution in Access is to use the SELECT DISTINCT (fields) INNER JOIN query on both lists to output non-duplicate data and here you can select one or more fields. Often I use the SELECT (fields), COUNT(*) GROUP BY (fields) HAVING COUNT(*)>1 query to output all the duplicate data.